# How to save image from PhotosPicker? - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

When converting a UIImage to data for saving to Firebase I use `.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)` however for Image I get the following errors,

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding'
>
> Referencing subscript 'subscript(dynamicMember:)' requires wrapper 'Binding' Insert '$'
>
> Value of type 'Image' has no dynamic member 'jpegData' using key path from root type 'Image'

How to save image from PhotosPicker?

**Code:**

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var avatarItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var avatarImage: Image?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PhotosPicker("Select avatar", selection: $avatarItem, matching: .images)

            avatarImage?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
        .onChange(of: avatarItem) {
            Task {
                if let loaded = try? await avatarItem?.loadTransferable(type: Image.self) {
                    avatarImage = loaded
                } else {
                    print("Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func upload() {
    if let data = avatarImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) { //ERROR HERE
        //Upload
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using a `UIImage` instead of `Image`.
This allows you to get to the jpegData, whereas from an `Image` View you cannot.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var avatarItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var avatarImage: UIImage?  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 77) {
            PhotosPicker("Select avatar", selection: $avatarItem, matching: .images)
            
            if let uiimg = avatarImage {
                Image(uiImage: uiimg)  // <--- here
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            }
            
            Button("Upload") { upload() } // <--- for testing
            
        }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            .onChange(of: avatarItem) {
                // <--- here
                Task {
                    if let data = try? await avatarItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                            avatarImage = uiImage
                        } else {
                            print("Failed")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
    func upload() {
        if let data = avatarImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) {
            // ....
            print("----> data: \(data)")
        }
    }
}
```